# SQL Server spending a lot of time creating sp_dbmmonitorupdate

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance, mirroring

I have an SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard with around 80 databases, 18 of which are a synchronous mirror primary.

I'm having a lot of complaints about database speed lately, so I've started digging with [`sp_askbrent`](http://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/). By far, the biggest issue, by orders of magnitude is this, repeatedly, per 5-minute interval:

> Query stats during the sample:
>   Executions: 18
>   Elapsed Time: 6666016
>   CPU Time: 2863281
>   Logical Reads: 153
>   Logical Writes: 0
>   CLR Time: 0
>
> Query stats since 2014-06-29 08:53:00.870
>   Executions: 3567174 - Percent of Server Total: 0.20%
>   Elapsed Time: 531346223556 - Percent of Server Total: 68.80%
>   CPU Time: 424387988112 - Percent of Server Total: 65.50%
>   Logical Reads: 35033946 - Percent of Server Total: 0.14%
>   Logical Writes: 22081 - Percent of Server Total: 0.44%
>   CLR Time: 0 - Percent of Server Total: 0.00%

it is creating a stored procedure [`sys.sp_dbmmonitorupdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms403827.aspx), seemingly at least once per database per 5 minute interval, and it's taking a huge CPU toll. Why would it be doing this? Is there anything I can do to stop it? Is it nessesary? Should I be stopping SQL mirroring? Why is it creating an SP every time, rather than creating it once, and then running it when required?

The query, in its fullness:

```
create procedure sys.sp_dbmmonitorupdate 
(
    @database_name      sysname = null  -- if null update all mirrored databases
)
as
begin
    set nocount on
    if (is_srvrolemember(N'sysadmin') <> 1 )
    begin
        raiserror(21089, 16, 1)
        return 1
    end
    if ( db_name() != N'msdb' )
    begin
        raiserror(32045, 16, 1, N'sys.sp_dbmmonitorupdate')
        return 1
    end

    declare     @retcode    int

    if object_id ( N'msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_data', N'U' ) is null
    begin 
        create table msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_data (        -- go through the code to see if there SHOULD be nulls.
            database_id             smallint,
            role                    bit null,
            status                  tinyint null,
            witness_status          tinyint null,
            log_flush_rate          bigint null,
            send_queue_size         bigint null,
            send_rate               bigint null,
            redo_queue_size         bigint null,
            redo_rate               bigint null,
            transaction_delay       bigint null,
            transactions_per_sec    bigint null,
            time                    datetime,
            end_of_log_lsn          numeric(25,0),
            failover_lsn            numeric(25,0),
            local_time              datetime
        )

        exec @retcode = msdb.dbo.sp_MS_marksystemobject dbm_monitor_data
        if ( @@error != 0 OR @retcode != 0 )
        begin
            raiserror( 32038, 16, 1 )
            return 1
        end

        create clustered index dbmmonitor1 
            on msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_data (database_id asc, time asc )
    end

    -- TO DO: create some keys depending on enterences.
    -- TO DO: make sure that the rows are unique
    if object_id ( N'msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_alerts', N'U' ) is null
    begin
        create table msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_alerts (
            database_id             smallint,
            retention_period        int null,   --this defaults to 7 days.  checked during the table update
            time_behind             int null,
            enable_time_behind      bit null,
            send_queue              int null,
            enable_send_queue       bit null,
            redo_queue              int null,
            enable_redo_queue       bit null,
            average_delay           int null,
            enable_average_delay    bit null
        )

        exec @retcode = msdb.dbo.sp_MS_marksystemobject dbm_monitor_alerts
        if ( @@error != 0 OR @retcode != 0 )
        begin
            raiserror( 32038, 16, 2 )
            return 1
        end
    end

    if ( select name from sys.database_principals where name = N'dbm_monitor') is null 
    begin
        create role dbm_monitor
        grant select on object::msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_data to dbm_monitor
    end

    if @database_name is not null
    begin
        --
        -- Check if the database specified exists 
        --
        if not exists (select * from master.sys.databases where name = @database_name)
        begin
            raiserror(15010, 16, 1, @database_name)
            return 1
        end
        -- 
        -- Check to see if it is mirrored
        --
        if (select mirroring_guid from master.sys.database_mirroring where database_id = db_id(@database_name)) is null 
        begin
            raiserror(32039, 16, 1, @database_name)
            return 1
        end

    declare
        @database_id            smallint,
        @role                   bit,
        @status                 tinyint,
        @witness_status         tinyint,
        @log_flush_rate         bigint ,
        @send_queue_size        bigint ,
        @send_rate              bigint ,
        @redo_queue_size        bigint ,
        @redo_rate              bigint ,
        @transaction_delay      bigint ,
        @transactions_per_sec   bigint ,
        @time                   datetime ,
        @end_of_log_lsn         numeric(25,0),
        @failover_lsn           numeric(25,0),
        @local_time             datetime

    declare
        @retention_period       int,
        @oldest_date            datetime

        set @database_id = DB_ID( @database_name )

-- To select the correct perf counter, we need the instance name.
        declare 
            @perf_instance1     nvarchar(256),
            @perf_instance2     nvarchar(256),
            @instance           nvarchar(128)

        select @instance = convert( nvarchar,  serverproperty(N'instancename'))
        if @instance is null
        begin
            set @instance = N'SQLServer'
        end
        else
        begin
            set @instance = N'MSSQL$' + @instance
        end

        set @perf_instance1 = left(@instance, len(@instance)) + N':Database Mirroring'
        set @perf_instance2 = left(@instance, len(@instance)) + N':Databases'

--
-- Insert a single row in the table for each database
--
-- 1. Pull out the perf counters
-- 2. Pull out the information from sys.database_mirroring
-- 3. Get the end of log lsn

        declare @perfcounters table(
            counter_name        nchar(128),
            cntr_value          bigint
        )

        insert into @perfcounters select counter_name, cntr_value from sys.dm_os_performance_counters where
            (object_name = @perf_instance1 or object_name = @perf_instance2 ) and 
            instance_name = @database_name and
            counter_name IN (N'Log Send Queue KB', N'Log Bytes Sent/sec', N'Redo Queue KB', N'Redo Bytes/sec', N'Transaction Delay', N'Log Bytes Flushed/sec', N'Transactions/sec')
        -- TO DO select all perfcounters for all databases so that you only need to access them once.
        select @role = (mirroring_role - 1),
            @status = mirroring_state, 
            @witness_status = mirroring_witness_state,
            @failover_lsn = mirroring_failover_lsn,
            @end_of_log_lsn = mirroring_end_of_log_lsn
                from sys.database_mirroring where database_id = @database_id
        -- TO DO: when doing the join, store the database id.
        select @log_flush_rate = cntr_value from @perfcounters where counter_name = N'Log Bytes Flushed/sec'
        select @send_queue_size = cntr_value from @perfcounters where counter_name = N'Log Send Queue KB'
        select @send_rate = cntr_value from @perfcounters where counter_name = N'Log Bytes Sent/sec'
        select @redo_queue_size = cntr_value from @perfcounters where counter_name = N'Redo Queue KB'
        select @redo_rate = cntr_value from @perfcounters where counter_name = N'Redo Bytes/sec'
        select @transaction_delay = cntr_value from @perfcounters where counter_name = N'Transaction Delay'
        select @transactions_per_sec = cntr_value from @perfcounters where counter_name = N'Transactions/sec'
        set @time = getutcdate()
        set @local_time = getdate()

-- 4. and insert it here
        insert into msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_data (database_id, role, status, witness_status, failover_lsn, end_of_log_lsn, log_flush_rate,
                send_queue_size, send_rate, redo_queue_size, redo_rate, transaction_delay, transactions_per_sec, time, local_time)
        values( @database_id, @role, @status, @witness_status, @failover_lsn, @end_of_log_lsn, @log_flush_rate, @send_queue_size, @send_rate,
            @redo_queue_size, @redo_rate, @transaction_delay, @transactions_per_sec, @time, @local_time )

        -- 
        -- Raise the alerts (as errors)
        --
        --
        -- we need to call sys.sp_dbmmonitorresults to get the last row inserted and then we will compare those results with what is in the alerts table
        --
        declare @alert      bit,
                @threshold  int,
                @command    char(256),
                @time_behind_alert_value    datetime,
                @send_queue_alert_value     int,
                @redo_queue_alert_value     int,
                @average_delay_alert_value  int,
                @temp_time                  int

        declare @results table(
            database_name           sysname,    -- Name of database
            role                    int,        -- 1 = Principal, 2 = Mirror
            mirroring_state         int,        -- 0 = Suspended, 1 = Disconnected, 2 = Synchronizing, 3 = Pending Failover, 4 = Synchronized
            witness_status          int,        -- 1 = Connected, 2 = Disconnected
            log_generation_rate     int NULL,   -- in kb / sec
            unsent_log              int,        -- in kb
            send_rate               int NULL,   -- in kb / sec
            unrestored_log          int,        -- in kb
            recovery_rate           int NULL,   -- in kb / sec
            transaction_delay       int NULL,   -- in ms
            transactions_per_sec    int NULL,   -- in trans / sec
            average_delay           int,        -- in ms
            time_recorded           datetime,
            time_behind             datetime,
            local_time              datetime        
        )

        set @command = N'sys.sp_dbmmonitorresults ''' + replace(@database_name, N'''',N'''''') + N''',0,0'
        -- get just the values we want to test
        insert into @results exec (@command)
        select @time_behind_alert_value = time_behind, @send_queue_alert_value = unsent_log,
                @redo_queue_alert_value = unrestored_log, @average_delay_alert_value = average_delay
        from @results where database_name = @database_name

        -- These next four code blocks are the same:
        --  If the alert is enabled AND the value is above the threshold, fire the event
        -- The four code blocks are time behind, send queue, redo queue and average delay.

        -- time behind
        set @alert = 0  -- from SteveLi.  This will make sure that if there are problems with the select, the alert
                        -- will not accidentally fire.
        select @threshold = time_behind, @alert = enable_time_behind
            from msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_alerts where database_id = @database_id
        begin
            set @temp_time = datediff(minute, @time_behind_alert_value, getutcdate())
            if ( @alert = 1 and @threshold < @temp_time ) -- time_behind_alert_value is datetime
            begin
                raiserror( 32040, 10, 1, @temp_time, @threshold ) with log
            end
        end
        -- send queue
        set @alert = 0
        select @threshold = send_queue, @alert = enable_send_queue
            from msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_alerts where database_id = @database_id
        begin
            if ( @alert = 1 and @threshold < @send_queue_alert_value )
            begin
                raiserror( 32042, 10, 2, @send_queue_alert_value, @threshold ) with log
            end
        end
        -- redo queue
        set @alert = 0
        select @threshold = redo_queue, @alert = enable_redo_queue
            from msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_alerts where database_id = @database_id
        begin
            if ( @alert = 1 and @threshold < @redo_queue_alert_value )
            begin
                raiserror( 32043, 10, 3, @redo_queue_alert_value, @threshold ) with log
            end
        end
        -- average delay
        set @alert = 0
        select @threshold = average_delay, @alert = enable_average_delay
            from msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_alerts where database_id = @database_id
        begin
            if ( @alert = 1 and @threshold < @average_delay_alert_value )
            begin
                raiserror( 32044, 10, 4, @average_delay_alert_value, @threshold ) with log
            end
        end

        -- Prune the Data Table.
        select @retention_period = retention_period from msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_alerts where database_id = @database_id
        if @retention_period is null
            set @retention_period = 168 -- 168 hours is equivalent to 7 days
        set @oldest_date = getutcdate() - (@retention_period / 24.)
        delete from msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_data where time < @oldest_date and database_id = @database_id
    end
    -- OK, this SP was called with no database specified.
    -- We are going to go through all the databases that are mirrored and update them.
    else
    begin
        declare dbmCursor cursor local scroll 
            for select 
                database_id 
            from sys.database_mirroring 
            where mirroring_guid is not null

        open dbmCursor
        fetch next from dbmCursor
            into @database_id

        while @@fetch_status=0
        begin
-- Better make sure sys.sp_dbmmonitorupdate with a null parameter.  Could cause real bad problems.
            set @database_name = db_name( @database_id )
            if @database_name is not null
            begin

                exec sys.sp_dbmmonitorupdate @database_name
                fetch next from dbmCursor
                    into @database_id
            end
        end

        close dbmCursor
        deallocate dbmCursor
    end

return 0
end
```

Comment: You're looking at stats over 5 months. Are you sure that CPU time is actually statistically significant? Aside from wait stats, have you done anything to point to actual slowness or CPU usage (like actual CPU on the box in real time, not CPU time aggregated over months) that can be correlated specifically to this procedure?

Comment: `msdb.dbo.dbm_monitor_data` comes from - If you are running database mirroring monitor or have SQL Agent job that is  created by the database mirroring monitor enabled. You should disable it and use DMVs instead `sys.database_mirroring`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand right now I'm in early moments of troubleshooting (literally the first hour). This particular server is CPU bound a lot of the time, so I've focused on high CPU counts. `65.50%` percent of server CPU times is what got my attention.

Comment: I agree with @Kin - are you actually using the data this thing is collecting for you? If not, shut it off.

Comment: @AaronBertrand nope I'm not. I've never once reviewed the mirroring log. I'll shut it down and see what kind of impact it makes.